# C++ undeclared identifier when trying to create an instance of a struct

Tags: c++, struct, undeclared-identifier

I have a struct that is declared in a C++ header file with the line:

```
struct AII_Common_Export message{
    ...
};
```

I am then trying to create an instance of that struct in a C++ source file, so that I can set/ use some of the attributes stored in the struct:

```
message data;
```

However, when I compile my code, I get an "undeclared identifier" error on this line... I have included the header file in the source file, so I don't understand why I am getting this error- can someone explain it to me?

I also tried creating the instance of it with:

```
AII_Common_Export message data;
```

But then got the compile error: "syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'data'.

Any ideas how I can fix this, so that I can create an instance of the struct?

**EDIT**

I have just found the `AII_Common_Export` definition- it is defined with:

```
#    define AII_Common_Export ACE_Proper_Import_Flag
```

and the `ACE_Proper_Import_Flag` is defined with:

```
#define ACE_Proper_Import_Flag __declspec (dllimport)
```

These two definitions are in separate header files.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I presume that is a define for something else

Comment: @MarcoA. pretty right! soneone2088, did you include such header?

Comment: @MarcoA. But this isn't a correct syntax anyway.

Comment: @OP: Post the code that defines `AII_Common_Export`. @Korbi I didn't say that's correct, I just guessed

Comment: @MarcoA. After "struct" must be the name of the struct. Not more no less, i guess.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in my OP, I have included the header file...

Comment: The header file was not written by me, and is currently being used in other cpp files, so the struct definition is correct. I'm just not sure whether I am using it correctly...?

Comment: @Korbi: This is incorrect. It's not standard C++, but a lot of compilers place export directives between struct/class and the name. You commonly use a macro to hide the differences or for redefining it when importing it. You'd expect a #define AII_Common_Export __declspec(dllexport) or some kind of equivalent somewhere - OP just needs to make sure that define is visible too

Comment: @ltjax Wow. I didn't hear of this before. Sorry.

Comment: @Itjax, thanks for your comment, I have just found those definitions, and added them to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Just do.

```
 struct message{
        ...
    };

message data;
```

see http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/

Comment: That is exactly what I have done- as mentioned in my OP, the struct is defined in the header with: `struct message{...};`, and I am creating an instance of it in the cpp with: `message data;`, but I'm getting this error...

Comment: you did" struct AII_Common_Export message{
    ...
};"
Thats not correct. You have to remove "message" or "AII_Common_Export".

Comment: I didn't write the header file- it was written by someone else, and is currently being used by other cpp files, so I must assume the definition of the struct is correct as it stands...

Comment: In that case you are missing another header which defines `All_Common_export`.

Comment: I have included the header file in which `AII_Common_export` is defined, but am now getting an error which says "use of undefined type 'message'"....